# Spring Data JPA Repository with Hibernate - persist (sql insert) parent entity but only update nested child entities

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data

I'm developing a Spring Boot app with Spring data, JPA, Hibernate combination. Below is the scenario I'm struggling with where the expected behavior is to update only some child entities while the parent entity is being inserted as new.

> Entity classes

```
@Entity
public class A {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn (name = "B_ID")
  @Cascade ( { CascadeType.ALL } )
  private B b;
}

@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class B {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @OneToMany (mappedBy = "b")
  @Cascade ( { CascadeType.ALL } )
  private Set<A> as;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn (name = "C_ID")
  @Cascade ( { CascadeType.ALL } )
  private C c;
}


@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class C {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @OneToMany (mappedBy = "c")
  @Cascade ( { CascadeType.ALL } )
  private Set<B> bs;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn (name = "D_ID")
  @Cascade ( { CascadeType.ALL } )
  private D d;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn (name = "E_ID")
  @Cascade ( { CascadeType.ALL } )
  private E e;
}


@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class D {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @OneToMany (mappedBy = "d")
  @Cascade ( { CascadeType.ALL } )
  private Set<C> cs;
}

@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class E {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @OneToMany (mappedBy = "e")
  @Cascade ( { CascadeType.ALL } )
  private Set<C> cs;
}
```

Below are the steps I'm performing in the app:

1. Pull `B` from repo; if it exists, update some of its field values [Or] create new `B` with field values.
2. Create new instance of `A` and set `B` into `A`.
3. Persist `A` (by invoking `JpaCrudRepository.save(A)`).

Success part:
Everything works fine when `B` doesn't exist in repo already. Which means:

1. New instances of `B` (and `C`,`D`,`E`) are created,
2. This newly created `B` is set into `A`,
3. And `A` is persisted to repo successfully (a new row is inserted in all corresponding tables in DB/repo).

Failure part:

1. Now, when `B` already exists in repo, the existing `B` is pulled properly,
2. Some fields of `B` are updated while `C`, `D`, `E` are left untouched,
3. And this updated `B` is set into `A`.
4. But when trying to persist `A` now a Unique constraint violation is thrown on `D` and `E`.

All the entities are marked with following:

```
• ID as auto-generated column (used as PK implicitly),
• Mapping between entities using the ID column,
• CascadeType ALL wherever mappings like OneToMany, ManyToOne are applied,
• Dynamic update annotation.
```

So far what I could gather from around the web on this subject:

*The JPA Repository doesn't have merge() or update() operations available explicitly, and the save() is supposed to cover those. And this save() operation works by calling merge() if the entity instance exists already Or by calling persist() if it is new. And digging further, the entity's ID column is being used to determine its existence in the repo. If this ID is null, entity is determined as new, and as existing if ID is not null.*

So in my failure case above, as the existing `B` entity instance is being pulled from the repo, it already has a non-null ID.

So I'm not currently clear on what exactly I'm missing here.
I tried finding any matching solution online but couldn't arrive at one yet.

Can someone please help me identify what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: Show us the code for `A` - `E`, including only the associations (other attributes are not required).

Comment: Thanks for looking! I have added the models [A to E] in the post.

Comment: The question is still unclear. You say that when `B` already exists, `C`, `D` and `E` are left untouched and yet you get a unique constraint violation on `D` and `E`, which can only occur if an insert is attempted on `D` and `E`, which according to your claim is not being attempted. That doesn't sound right. This is a debugging problem specific to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue and solution. As A and B were being created as new, subsequently C,D,E were all created as new which caused the violation. So to solve this I had to pull each existing entity of C,D,and E from the DB, and set them respectively/hierarchically inside the newly created B entity, before attempting to persist.

Basically, don't create new instance for an entity if it is nested within a parent entity which is about to be persisted.. and the goal is to update when a similar record already exists.